# Equals() and indexOf() not working as I'd expect using NumberFormat

Tags: java, number-formatting

I'm attempting to check if a string(filter) is contained in another string(formattedAmount) i.e. is filter a substring of formattedAmount.

I could not get it to work so I just changed the code to use "equals()" instead of "indexOf()", purely for simplyfing the testing. The equals method does not appear to be working as I would expect either.

Here is a dummy script I wrote up that replicates what I am trying to do:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;


public class utils
{

    public utils()
    {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {   
        String filter = "333 333,44";
        Number amount = new BigDecimal(333333.44);

        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
        nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

        String formattedAmount = nf.format(amount);

        if (formattedAmount.equals(filter)) 
        {
            System.out.println("Working");
            }
    }
}
```

Any Ideas why it is not entering the If statement?

Thanks

Comment: Have you actually tried to print the formattedAmount variable and see what you get?

Comment: I have Tudor, it prints 333 333,44 as I'd expect.

Comment: @Thomas Buckley: As I suspected, the fourth character is indeed not space, but something else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple `println` will reveal the truth: the FRANCE locale thousands separator is **NOT THE SPACE CHARACTER**:

```
System.out.println((int)formattedAmount.charAt(3) + " " + (int)filter.charAt(3));
```

Prints:

```
160 32
```

Hence, your two strings are not equal.

Try

```
char s = 160;
String filter = "333" + s + "333,44";
```

Comment: What is it? It sure looks like a space.

Comment: It sure did look like a space. Though if you check string bytes you'll see that it is not the same character as usual space.

Comment: @Shredder: 160 is Non-breaking space, 32 is Normal space, according to this: http://htmlhelp.com/reference/charset/iso160-191.html

Comment: I noticed the name of the character in that link is "nbsp", which seems to be the common html space encoding. But when I copy+paste from a webpage text using `&nbsp;` into the java program, and compare the string with a similar string I code with my space bar, you would think they wouldn't be equal like we see here, but they are.. Hmm. Thought i'd share, idk why XD

Comment: I guess browsers (at least IE) don't actually output this "non-breaking space", but just a regular space for `&nbsp;`.. even `&#160;`! I wonder why; that seems misleading. Anyway, irrelevant, I'll stop rambling. (added my answer to yours, feel free to rollback if you want)

Comment: All makes sense now guys...thanks for the answers and help :)

Answer (score 2):

String#equals lexicographically compares two strings. So for equals to return true both strings must have the same content.
Just checked that two strings have different characters: formattedAmount = 33 33 33 **c2 a0** 33 33 33 2c 34 34 vs filter = 33 33 33 **20** 33 33 33 2c 34 34. 0x20 is the standard space and 0xc2a0 is probably no-break-space.
No wonder equals return false - the strings have different characters after the first three '3's.

Answer (score 0):

`nf.format` is outputting a non-breaking space (character code 160) between the groups of 3's.  Your filter has a regular space in it (character code 32) so the strings don't match.